# Browser zoom breaks svg layout

Tags: javascript, html, svg, graphics, transformation

*(Refer code snippet)* I am trying to draw a path from bottom of one element `#item-A > div` inside of *foreignObject* `#item-A` to top of another element `#item-B > div` inside of *foreignObject* `#item-B`. The div(s) height is variable.

For different browser zoom level, the path `M ${item_A_div_Bottom - svgOffset.y}` value gives different result. This breaks the layout.

---

I went through various documents to try and understand the reason for this behaviour:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html
- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1
- https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/embedded.html

---

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var svgEl = document.querySelector('svg'),
    itemA = document.querySelector('#item-A'),
    itemB = document.querySelector('#item-B'),
    path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'path');

  const svgOffset = svgEl.getBoundingClientRect();
  const {
    a
  } = svgEl.getScreenCTM();

  const {
    x: item_A_BBoxX,
  } = itemA.getBBox();

  const {
    bottom: item_A_div_Bottom
  } = document.querySelector(`#item-A > div`).getBoundingClientRect();

  const {
    y: item_B_BBoxY,
  } = document.querySelector(`#item-B`).getBBox();

  const path_d = `
    M ${item_A_BBoxX},${(item_A_div_Bottom - svgOffset.y) * (1 / a)}
    V ${item_B_BBoxY}
  `;

  path.setAttribute('d', path_d);
  path.setAttribute('stroke', 'red');
  path.setAttribute('stroke-width', '2px');
  svgEl.appendChild(path);
}
```

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: purple;
}

#svg-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

svg {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
}

foreignObject {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="svg-wrapper">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    div {
      color: white;
      font: 18px serif;
      height: 40px;
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>

  <foreignObject id="item-A" x="20" y="20" width="60" height="30">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      Item-A
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
  
  <foreignObject id="item-B" x="20" y="120" width="60" height="30">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      Item-B
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
</div>
```

---

If you zoom-in or zoom-out and then re-run the code snippet, the path position changes and length.

How to keep the layout from breaking for different zoom levels?

Comment: png images will eliminate the problem. if svg is not necessary, replace it with a similar png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value of attributes returned by `element.getBoundingClientRect()` changes with browser zoom. As given in [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

> The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport. ....
>
> The amount of scrolling that has been done of the viewport area (or any other scrollable element) is taken into account when computing the bounding rectangle. This means that the rectangle's boundary edges (top, right, bottom, left) change their values every time the scrolling position changes (because their values are relative to the viewport and not absolute).

Instead of using `element.getBoundingClientRect()`, use `element.clientHeight` with `object.getBBox()` attributes to calculate the desired position.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var svgEl = document.querySelector('svg'),
    itemA = document.querySelector('#item-A'),
    itemB = document.querySelector('#item-B'),
    path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'path');

  const {
    clientTop: item_A_ClientTop,
    clientHeight: item_A_ClientHeight,
  } = itemA;

  const {
    x: item_A_BBoxX,
    y: item_A_BBoxY
  } = itemA.getBBox();

  const {
    clientHeight: item_A_div_ClientHeight
  } = document.querySelector(`#item-A > div`);

  const {
    y: item_B_BBoxY,
  } = document.querySelector(`#item-B`).getBBox();

  const path_d = `
    M ${item_A_BBoxX},${item_A_BBoxY + item_A_div_ClientHeight}
    V ${item_B_BBoxY}
  `;

  path.setAttribute('d', path_d);
  path.setAttribute('stroke', 'red');
  path.setAttribute('stroke-width', '2px');
  svgEl.appendChild(path);
}
```

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: purple;
}

#svg-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

svg {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
}

foreignObject {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="svg-wrapper">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    div {
      color: white;
      font: 18px serif;
      height: 40px;
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>

  <foreignObject id="item-A" x="20" y="20" width="60" height="30">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      Item-A
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
  
  <foreignObject id="item-B" x="20" y="120" width="60" height="30">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      Item-B
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
</div>
```